# Cannot see View after changing background of TextView

Tags: java, android

Okay I have a layout for my `ListView`'s items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/draweritemtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#111"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So all works fine with this setup. It shows up like this:

```
ITEM
-------
ITEM
-------
ITEM
-------
```

But I don't want the blue select color from android, so I would like to change it by changing the textviews background to `@drawable/drawer_active_selector`.
Here is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/notquiteverylightgray" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" />
</selector>
```

And my drawables

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="semitransparent_white">#77ffffff</drawable>
    <drawable name="verylightgray">#eee</drawable>
    <drawable name="notquiteverylightgray">#ddd</drawable>
    <drawable name="white">#fff</drawable>
</resources>
```

Now it will look like this:

```
ITEM
ITEM
ITEM
------
```

The padding is right, but the things I miss are the seperators (The `<View />`)

How can I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your solution. By default`ListView`'s item clicks are handled by the `ListView` itself, not by the child view that was clicked. So instead of changing the `TextView`'s background to `@drawable/drawer_active_selector` you should set the item selector drawable of the `ListView` using `android:listSelector` xml property or one of `List.setSelector()` methods. The other mistake concerns the dividers. Your solution is unnecessarily verbose. There is a much easier way to add dividers. Just use `ListView`'s `android:divider` property or `ListView.setDivider()` method.